# Dckable/Floating Panel/window C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, panel, dockpanel

I would like to know if there is some in-build component in C#/.net which can be used to create dockable windows/panel.

All the search on the internet only provides information on using some third party component/creating your own, but all these components have a lot of bugs.

Visual studio does it like for properties and solution explorer, but I could not find a component which can be used like that.

Also I do not want to extend the IDE, My application is Quite simple and does not need so many features.

Comment: I know it's not built in, but have you considered the Weifenluo DockPanel suite? It's open source, and a significant user base.

Comment: I agree with Baldrick. I've used it my self and have not faced any issues so far.